# thematic/semantic presentation of all tags used in a Stack Exchange subsite

Tags: feature-request

Wouldn't it be useful to have a thematic listing, possibly hierarchically organized, of all tags used on a particular Stack Exchange subsite? There is the "Tags" button, but clicking on it leads to a long list that would take a long time to semantically browse.

At least it would be useful to have a page that discusses similar tags and how they (are meant to) differ. I am having in mind a community wiki page with different paragraphs by topic *and/or* paragraphs for each set of tags that are related but commonly confused/mislabeled.

Comment: That list isn't really "unorganized" considering there's three ways you can sort it: popular (number of questions), name (alphabetical), and new (creation date). How would you suggest it be better "organized"?

Comment: @animuson You are right in that "unorganized" might be too strong a word choice. I was thinking mainly of thematic/hierarchical organization or simply a long structured page describing the different tags' relation to each other and common mistagging pitfalls.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that would be quite nice. Kind of like an interactive word cloud, [as shown here](http://www.jasondavies.com/wordcloud/):

[image]

Clicking on such a tag would then allow to "semantically" navigate to the next tag cloud.
This would be a different representation of something that already exists today: You can click on a tag and see its related tags listed on the right:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java#h-related-tags

Comment: An interactive word cloud would sound nice, except the one you're showing is a bit too chaotic :-) A network of clouds like what you see on the [list of all Stack Exchange sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites), except with smaller text, all explanations visible, and lines between the clouds would be a better visual representation of the data.